# Правильное использование промисов

Tags: node.js, promise

Уже это обсуждалось несколько раз, но я всё равно не могу понять до конца...

Надеюсь смогу разобраться с вашей помощью :-)

Например мне необходимо выполнить последовательно запросы к БД и произвести определенные действия.
Сейчас я делаю так:

```js
await model.findAll({
    where: ...
  })
  .then(data => {
    что - то делаю с ответом
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => {
    опять что - то делаю с ответ и например дальше нужно делать еще запросы исходя из текущих ответов
    const options = {
      id: data.userId,
      user: data.color
    }
    await model.create(options)
      .then(createData => {
        for (const item of elem) {
          await model.destroy({
            where: ...
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(err)
  })
  .catch(err)
```

т.е. в частности меня интересует на сколько я правильно делаю с "вложенным" then/catch.
Я это представляю себе так что в случае ошибки каждый catch будет на своём уровне отлавливать ошибку (на самом деле у меня более "вложенная" структура) и это вроде как реально работает :-), но вот на сколько правильно я это использую всё?

Comment: Всего в кучу намешано, и await и then... Так нельзя же. await работает только внутри функции с async и эти ключевые слова нужны как раз для того, чтобы эти монструозные конструкции колбэков не делать. Можно пояснить, зачем? Есть ли какой-нибудь более конкретный и воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: Да верно, моя ошибка, при наборе пропустил это, они везде async и каждый запрос к БД с await. 
да вот и были сомнения :-) В ответе посоветовали с try catch и кажется я понял :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно с какой точки зрения? Я пишу по разному в зависимости от условий.
Если говорить о синтаксисе, то как минимум на строчке

```
await model.create(options)
```

возникнет ошибка, так как на строчке

```
.then(data => {
    опять что - то делаю с ответ
```

ты не помечаешь функцию как `async`. (и на строчке `await model.destroy({` тоже)

По поводу вложенности `catch` - сейчас да, каждый catch отлавливает ошибку только на своем уровне вложенности. Но можно оставить только 1 внешний catch и он будет ловить все ошибки (иногда нужно специфическим образом обрабатывать ошибку на одном из уровней вложенности, но как правило 1 catch хватает).

С точки зрения читаемости предлагаю переписать код приблизительно так:

```
const MyAwesomeMethod = async function() {
  try {
    const data = await model.findAll({
      where: ...
    });

    const data1 = что - то делаю с ответом
    const data2 = опять что - то делаю с ответ

    const options = {
      id: data.userId,
      user: data.color
    }

    const createData = await model.create(options);

    // в используемом тобой цикле for of ты будешь дожидаться окончания каждого удаления и выполнять их последовательно
    // с Promise.all можно выполнять удаления параллельно
    await Promise.all(
       elem.map(item => model.destroy({
           where: ...
       })
    );

  } catch (err) {
    conslole.log('wait! oh shh...');
  }
}
```

Comment: ой точно, я просто пропустил, на самом деле то что в начале написано про async я использую, но почему-то тут забыл :-(

Большое спасибо за ответ! Я кажется понял :-)
Всё таки лучше один раз увидеть на своём примере, сразу становится понятно